# How can I get a leaflet.js instance using only a DOM object?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, leaflet, knockout-2.0

I'm right now building a custom Knockout.js binding to handle drawing of polygons. In this case the Knockout API only gives me a reference to a DOM object to access whatever it is I need to update. However, it looks like by design leaflet.js wants the user to store the map instance in their implementation. I don't have that option.

Trying this gave me an error: `var existingMap = L.map('aMapIDGoesHere')`

And the error was: `map already initialized`.

Any way I can use a DOM element or element ID to access the map instance?

By request here's the custom binding, please note it's a work in progress:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.leafletDraw = {
  init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
    var map = L.map(element).setView([40, -90], 3);
    var tiles = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: 'OSM',
        minZoom: 2
    }).addTo(map);

    // Initialise the FeatureGroup to store editable layers
    var editableLayers = new L.FeatureGroup();
    map.addLayer(editableLayers);

    // Initialise the draw control and pass it the FeatureGroup of editable layers
    var drawOptions = {
      edit: {
        featureGroup: editableLayers,
        remove: false
      },
      draw: {
        polyline: false,
        circle: false,
        marker: false,
        polygon: {
          allowIntersection: false,
          showArea: true
        }
      }
    }
    var drawControl = new L.Control.Draw(drawOptions);
    map.addControl(drawControl);

    // when a shape is first created
    map.on('draw:created', function (e) {
      var shapeString = $.map(e.layer._latlngs, function(pair) { return pair.lng.toString()+"::"+pair.lat.toString(); }).join(";;;");
      var value = valueAccessor();
      if (ko.isObservable(value)) {
        value(shapeString);
      }

      editableLayers.addLayer(e.layer);

      drawControl.removeFrom(map);
      drawOptions.draw.polygon = false;
      drawOptions.draw.rectangle = false;
      var editControl = new L.Control.Draw(drawOptions);
      map.addControl(editControl);
    });

    // handle when a shape is edited
    map.on('draw:edited', function (e) {
      var editedLayer = e.layers._layers[Object.keys(e.layers._layers)[0]];
      var shapeString = $.map(editedLayer._latlngs, function(pair) { return pair.lng.toString()+"::"+pair.lat.toString(); }).join(";;;");
      var value = valueAccessor();
      if (ko.isObservable(value)) {
        value(shapeString);
      }
    });
  },
  update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
    // need to figure this out since we can't access leaflet params from 
  }
};
```

**Special Note** You'll notice that I am converting points into a concatenated string. This is necessary for the time being.

Comment: Could you add your code ?

Comment: @leszek.hanusz done. The part where the code matters is under the `update` property at the bottom. No way to grab a map instance there using just `element`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As long as you are sure that the DOM element will not be removed, you could just add it as a subproperty on the DOM element itself. Here's a binding handler using the code on the leaflet front page for setting up the leaflet map:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.leaflet = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor){
        var map = L.map(element);
        element.myMapProperty = map;
        L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        }).addTo(map);
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor){
        var existingMap = element.myMapProperty;
        var value = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
        var latitude = ko.unwrap(value.latitude);
        var longitude = ko.unwrap(value.longitude);
        var zoom = ko.unwrap(value.zoom);
        existingMap.setView([latitude, longitude], zoom);
    }
};
```

To use the binding handler you would just bind like the following:

```
<div data-bind="leaflet: { latitude: latitudeProperty, longitude: longitudeProperty, zoom: zoomProperty }"></div>
```

Just ensure that you have also styled the `div` to ensure it has a height and width. I have written [a jsfiddle which uses the above leaflet bindingHandler](http://jsfiddle.net/23qq8/) where you could try it out.

I have only tested this jsfiddle in Internet Explorer 11, Firefox 26.0 and Firefox 27.0.1.

Comment: Wow, never thought to actually store it within the DOM object itself. Nice thinking :) In my use case, if the DOM object is removed then there's no reason to access it further anyways. Thanks for this!

Comment: You might want to look into `ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback` to ensure you dispose the map object and event listeners if the DOM object is removed. Something like `ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function(){ element.myMapProperty.remove(); });` or similar should probably work just fine. (Observe, the code in this comment is completely untested.)

Answer (score 0):

noting that in very limited circumstances, this could be a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60836683/1116657

```
window[Object.keys(window).find(key => key.substr(0,3) === "map")];
```

Read my original post for comments on it's brittleness and limitations, but thought this could be helpful to someone. Thanks!